# What does user@mail:~$ mean?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have an Ubuntu Server on version Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I'm confused about the following. Usually in the terminal it's like that: `user@nameofdevice:~$` but for any reason it's now `user@mail:~$` and I don't know why and what it means.

Comment: Same as this on macOS - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal

Comment: Thanks. I changed it with `sudo hostname myhostname`

Comment: Somebody better write up an answer...

Comment: @harrymc - all yours. I don't know enough nix to know whether that is directly translatable from macOS.

Comment: Since this results from the prompt, you need to specify which shell you are running, and how your prompt is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the contents of **/etc/hostname** have somehow been changed. let's assume you're using *mail.domain.com* and it's made the "pretty" hostname *mail*.

to fix this you want to utilize `hostnamectl`, which, if you type the command by it's self it will output what everything is currently set to.

to proceed to change the hostname run `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname "hostname.example.com"`

to change the "pretty" hostname you can apply the --pretty flag to the command and run `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname --pretty "hostname"`